# How to re-load page while looping over elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

This is my code, should be easily recreateable:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def main():
    # Setup chrome options
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Ensure GUI is off
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x3500")

    # Set path to chromedriver as per your configuration
    webdriver_service = Service("/home/sumant/chromedriver/stable/chromedriver")

    # Choose Chrome Browser
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Get page
    url =  "https://www.ibrance.com/"
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    ele = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for i, e in enumerate(ele):
        try:
            print(e.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
            e.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.save_screenshot(f"/mnt/d/Work/ss{i}.png")
            driver.get(url)
            # driver.refresh()
        except:
            print("element not interactable")
    
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The idea is I click on a link take a screenshot, load home page again, click on next link and so on.
After the first link, it is not able to find any other element on the reloaded page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this worked
(Thanks YuMa, for the inspiration)

```
def main():
# ...


# Get page
    url =  "https://www.ibrance.com/"
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    total_element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    total_clicks = len(total_element)


    def get_images(ele, i):
        try:
            ele[i].click()
            time.sleep(2)
            # driver.save_screenshot(f"/mnt/d/Work/ss{i}.png")
            print(driver.title)
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            print("")
    

    for i in range(0, total_clicks+1):
        ele = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        get_images(ele, i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, since after the refresh it is unable to find you required elements.
To do so, elements need to be reloaded after each refresh.
Do this:

```
ele = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for i, e in enumerate(ele):
    try:
        print(e.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
        e.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.save_screenshot(f"/mnt/d/Work/ss{i}.png")
        driver.get(url)
        driver.refresh()
        # reload elements
        ele = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

Comment: throws the following error: `Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: Try removing the refresh, it is redundant.

Comment: ele = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for i range(len(ele)):
        ele = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        for a in range(1):
            try:
                print(ele[i].get_attribute('outerHTML'))
                ele[i].click()
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.save_screenshot(f"/mnt/d/Work/ss{i}.png")
                driver.get(url)
                driver.refresh()
                break

Comment: but then this will only get the first screenshot and then stop (if you add a break). I want to get a screenshot after clicking each element, hence the loop.

Comment: No, this should give you the full coverage of screenshots. the break is only in the first loop, and it returns you to the first one